# How can I connect to a Docker image via SSH from another docker image?

Tags: docker, ssh, ansible

Disclaimer: this might be a noob question. If so, I profusely aplogize, this isn't my goal at all.

I'm really new to Ansible, but even though Ansible is not (yet) the problem, I have an issue with my own configuration. TL;DR: I have no choice but to use Windows in my situation.

However, I am able to use Docker. I wrote the following Dockerfile to have something to run with:

```
FROM php:7.3.1-apache-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip git nano
RUN pip3 install ansible
RUN mkdir /home/devops
WORKDIR /home/devops
```

and I wrote the following docker-compose.yml file to have an Ansible dedicated server, and a "slave".

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  ansible:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  slave:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "22:22"
```

Following [this tutorial](http://sametmax.com/introduction-a-ansible-loutil-du-sysadmin-paresseux-mais-pragmatique/) (in French), they say that I need to login with SSH to the slave server from the "Ansible" server. However, even after putting my `id_rsa.pub` file into the "slave", I can't connect to it. Basically, it returns the following:

> connect to host 172.19.0.2 port 22: Connection refused

172.19.0.2 being the port it displays to me when I run `ifconfig`.

So I don't really know what I should do here. I saw some links about ssh issues with Docker online before asking here but I have no idea whether my problem is related with that.

Is there a simple way to do so? Or am I doing everything wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know exactly what is Ansible. But the idea of SSH-ing into a container doesn't seem legit! You may try to use the flag `-it` to attach to your docker. Try `docker exec -it container_name` from your host. Or if you want to have something accessible on both (share data) use a storage solution, like volumes.

Comment: I know the Docker basics, but I'm totally lost with Ansible, and it seems that I encountered the worst tutorial to get started in my case

Comment: Check here: dockermastery.slack.com
They may solve your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The architecture you're designing doesn't really match how either Ansible or Docker work.

Ansible doesn't have a client/server architecture: you don't need to install a "master Ansible server" container, you just need some way to connect to the host you're trying to manage using ssh.

Docker containers rarely run ssh daemons.  They are typically packaging of some single server.  A container might run, say, an Apache server and absolutely nothing else.  This makes them hard to manage using Ansible.

I would suggest installing Ansible on your host directly, possibly packaged in a Python virtual environment.  (This gets around tricky issues with sharing credentials like ssh keys with the container, and it means you don't need root permissions just to run the tool.)  For managing Docker containers, I would recommend reading up on [the `docker build` system to build custom Docker images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/); this typically involves a half-dozen lines of `Dockerfile` to install a service and tell Docker how to start it.

Comment: I guess you're right, I think I just got lost because of the fact that I have to use Windows. Now that I'm back home with a good old Ubuntu, I'll restart from zero

Answer (score 1):

Do you have open ssh server?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo ufw allow 22
```

For ansible

```
- name: 2.Install Open ssh
  apt: name=openssh-server

- name: 8.Update firewall
  become: true
  command: ufw allow from any to any port 22 proto tcp
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it!

You can use docker-compose's link. Aaaand you need to install openssh-server and turn it on.

So,

your Dockerfile should be like

```
FROM php:7.3.1-apache-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip git nano openssh-server
RUN pip3 install ansible
RUN mkdir /home/devops
RUN service ssh start
WORKDIR /home/devops
```

and your docker-compose should be like:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  ansible:
    build: .
    links:
      - slave:slave
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  slave:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "22:22"
```

So, you only need to mount as a volume your id-rsa in ansible and the id-rsa.pub in slave.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  ansible:
    build: .
    links:
      - slave:slave
    volumes:
      - /path/to/your/id-rsa:/home/root/.ssh/id-rsa
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  slave:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /path/to/your/id-rsa.pub:/home/root/.ssh/id-rsa.pub
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "22:22"
```

Hope it helps.